# How to Segregates Events by username in Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm automating AWS Cloudwatch Events by using Cloudformation.

I want to Segragates the Events by **type: root** if any root activities happen we need to get alert.

How to write the code in InputPathsMap

```
EventRule01:
    Type: AWS::Events::Rule
    Properties:
      Name: !Join
        - ""
        - - !GetAtt ResourceListAccountAlias.accountAlias
          - Root-Account-Change-Detected
      Description: "Triggers an alarm when AWS Root Account"
      State: "ENABLED"
      Targets:
        - Arn: !Ref AlarmNotificationTopic01
          Id: "001"
          InputTransformer:
            InputPathsMap:
              eventSource: "$.detail.eventSource"
              accountId: "$.detail.userIdentity.accountId"
              principalId: "$.detail.userIdentity.principalId"
              type: "$.detail.userIdentity"
              eventTime: "$.detail.eventTime"
              eventName: "$.detail.eventName"
            InputTemplate: |
              "The following event: <eventSource> was detected: <eventName> in account: <accountId>"

              "This event was initiated by: <principalId> for this Account: <type> on: <eventTime>"

      EventPattern:
        detail-type:
          - "AWS API Call via CloudTrail"
        detail:
          eventSource:
            - "signin.amazonaws.com"
          eventName:
            - "ConsoleLogin"
```

Answer (score 0):

`InputPathsMap` is not for segregation of events. So you can't do what you want to do. You have to create different rules for different users, or direct all events into a **lambda function**. The function can then distribute the event further based on the event's body.